# Why does choosing the method break the parallel computation?

Tags: differential-equations, parallelization

I have a workable function with using NDSolve with predefined method for solving. But for some reasons I should use the parallel computation. The main problem is that the NDSolve can't build the structure for solving this problem with defined method, but if we remove the definition of method - it works.

The code of solving the problem is below:

```
 DOPRI54[] := 
  Module[{DOPRIamat, DOPRIbvec, DOPRIcvec, DOPRIevec, 
    DOPRICoefficients},
   DOPRIamat := {{1/5}, {3/40, 9/40}, {44/45, -56/15, 
      32/9}, {19372/6561, -25360/2187, 
      64448/6561, -212/729}, {9017/3168, -355/33, 46732/5247, 
      49/176, -5103/18656}, {35/384, 0, 500/1113, 125/192, -2187/6784,
       11/84}}; 
   DOPRIbvec := {35/384, 0, 500/1113, 125/192, -2187/6784, 11/84, 0}; 
   DOPRIcvec := {1/5, 3/10, 4/5, 8/9, 1, 1}; 
   DOPRIevec := {71/57600, 0, -71/16695, 71/1920, -17253/339200, 
     22/525, -1/40}; 
   DOPRICoefficients[5, p_] := 
    N[{DOPRIamat, DOPRIbvec, DOPRIcvec, DOPRIevec}, p];
   Return[{"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 5, 
     "Coefficients" -> DOPRICoefficients, "StiffnessTest" -> False}]
   ];

Fehlberg45[] := 
  Module[{Fehlbergamat, Fehlbergbvec, Fehlbergcvec, Fehlbergevec, 
    FehlbergCoefficients},
   Fehlbergamat := {{1/4}, {3/32, 9/32}, {1932/2197, -7200/2197, 
      7296/2197}, {439/216, -8, 3680/513, -845/4104}, {-8/27, 
      2, -3544/2565, 1859/4104, -11/40}}; 
   Fehlbergbvec := {25/216, 0, 1408/2565, 2197/4104, -1/5, 0}; 
   Fehlbergcvec := {1/4, 3/8, 12/13, 1, 1/2}; 
   Fehlbergevec := {-1/360, 0, 128/4275, 2197/75240, -1/50, -2/55}; 
   FehlbergCoefficients[4, p_] := 
    N[{Fehlbergamat, Fehlbergbvec, Fehlbergcvec, Fehlbergevec}, p];
   Return[{"ExplicitRungeKutta", 
     "Coefficients" -> FehlbergCoefficients, "DifferenceOrder" -> 4, 
     "EmbeddedDifferenceOrder" -> 5, "StiffnessTest" -> False}]
   ];

BS54[] := 
  Module[{}, 
   Return[{"ExplicitRungeKutta", 
     "Coefficients" -> "EmbeddedExplicitRungeKuttaCoefficients", 
     "DifferenceOrder" -> 5, "StiffnessTest" -> False}]];

ClassicalRK4[] := 
 Module[{crkamat, crkbvec, crkcvec, ClassicalRungeKuttaCoefficients},
  crkamat = {{1/2}, {0, 1/2}, {0, 0, 1}};
  crkbvec = {1/6, 1/3, 1/3, 1/6};
  crkcvec = {1/2, 1/2, 1};
  ClassicalRungeKuttaCoefficients[4, p_] := 
   N[{crkamat, crkbvec, crkcvec}, p];
  Return[{"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4, 
    "Coefficients" -> ClassicalRungeKuttaCoefficients}]
  ]

getMethods[methodname_] := Module[{method = ""},
  Switch[methodname, "DOPRI54", method = DOPRI54[], "Fehlberg45", 
   method = Fehlberg45[], "BS54", method = BS54[], "ClassicalRK4", 
   method = ClassicalRK4[]];
  Return[method]
  ]

getEquilibriumPoints[system_] := Block[{sol},
  sol = NSolve[{system == {0., 0., 0.}}, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}];
  Return[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol]
  ]
```

The problem part of the code (it has no problem for solving without parallelization):

```
gettingInLocality[system_, pointsCenters_, radius_, T_, u0_, 
  OptionsPattern[methodname -> "DOPRI54"]] := 
 Module[{set = {}, events, method},
  method = getMethods[OptionValue[methodname]];
  events = {(x[t] - #[[1]])^2 + (y[t] - #[[2]])^2 + (z[t] - #[[
            3]])^2 <= radius^2} & /@ pointsCenters;

  NDSolve[{{x'[t], y'[t], z'[t]} == 
       system, {x[0], y[0], z[0]} == #}, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 
      T}, Method -> {"EventLocator", 
       "Event" -> First /@ ## &[events], 
       "EventAction" :> 
        Throw[set = Append[set, {#, t}], "StopIntegration"], 
       "Method" -> method}] & /@ u0;
  Return[set]
  ]
```

The version of code with using parallelization:

```
gettingInLocality[system_, pointsCenters_, radius_, T_, u0_, 
  OptionsPattern[methodname -> "DOPRI54"]] := 
 Module[{set = {}, events, method},
  SetSharedVariable[set];
  method = getMethods[OptionValue[methodname]];
  events = {(x[t] - #[[1]])^2 + (y[t] - #[[2]])^2 + (z[t] - #[[
            3]])^2 <= radius^2} & /@ pointsCenters;

  ParallelMap[
   CriticalSection[{setClock}, 
     NDSolve[{{x'[t], y'[t], z'[t]} == 
        system, {x[0], y[0], z[0]} == #}, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 
       T}, Method -> {"EventLocator", 
        "Event" -> First /@ ## &[events], 
        "EventAction" :> 
         Throw[set = Append[set, {#, t, $KernelID}], 
          "StopIntegration"], "Method" -> method (*If we remove that part of code with choosing method - it works*)}]] &, u0];
  Return[set]
  ]
```

And the last part of code for solving the problem:

```
sigma  = 10; rho = 28 ; beta = N[8/3];
initdata = {19., -25., 10.};
system = {sigma (y[t] - x[t]), x[t] (rho - z[t]) - y[t], 
   x[t] y[t] - beta z[t]};
pointsCenters = getEquilibriumPoints[system][[{1, 2}]]
radius = 10;
T = 10.^3;
u0 = Flatten[
  Table[{x, y, z}, {x, -25., 25., 25.}, {y, -25., 25., 30.}, {z, 0., 
    50., 15.}], 2]
set = {};
set = gettingInLocality[system, pointsCenters, radius, T, u0];
```

The main problem is an errors about not correct structure of coefficients and initialization of the method failed. But if we remove the marked part of code (look parallel version of getting local) it works. In this case the choosing of the appropriate method is very important. How I can fix this?

The image of errors is below:

[image]

Comment: I did not find any errors. Both versions of the code work, but when using `ParallelMap` list `set` probably contains kernel number.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no error when executed and both methods produce equivalent output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DOPRI54[]` returns a list of rules containing a symbol `DOPRICoefficients$<<some number>>` <s>that does not exist anymore because it was scoped by `Module`</s> that has the attribute `Temporary`. Maybe temporary symbols are not automatically shared by `Parallel` and its ilk.

I believe that it would be a much better strategy to define `DOPRI54` (and many of the other symbols but I focus on this one) in a more encapsulated way.

In the followng, the actual function that you want to submit as option is a *pure function* (defined by the infix form `\[Function]` of `Function`). In order to inline the definitions `DOPRIamat`, `DOPRIbvec`, `DOPRIcvec`, and `DOPRIevec`, you may use `With`. Look at this:

```
ClearAll[DOPRI54];
DOPRI54 = With[{
   DOPRIamat = {{1/5}, {3/40, 9/40}, {44/45, -56/15, 32/9}, {19372/6561, -25360/2187, 64448/6561, -212/729}, {9017/3168, -355/33, 46732/5247, 49/176, -5103/18656}, {35/384, 0, 500/1113, 125/192, -2187/6784, 11/84}},
   DOPRIbvec = {35/384, 0, 500/1113, 125/192, -2187/6784, 11/84, 0},
   DOPRIcvec = {1/5, 3/10, 4/5, 8/9, 1, 1},
   DOPRIevec = {71/57600, 0, -71/16695, 71/1920, -17253/339200, 22/525, -1/40}
   },
   {
    "ExplicitRungeKutta",
    "DifferenceOrder" -> 5,
    "Coefficients" -> ({order, p} \[Function] N[{DOPRIamat, DOPRIbvec, DOPRIcvec, DOPRIevec}, p]),
   "StiffnessTest" -> False
    }]
```

I have not tested this but I believe that this is much better encapsulated. This is also essential for preventing the parallel kernels from calling the main kernel (which is essential for scalability).

Moreover, make sure to learn the difference between `SetDelayed` (`:=`) and `Set` (`=`). You really want to use `Set` here.

Comment: I suspect the `Module`-localized variables, while `Temporary`, stick around for a while in the main kernel (IIRC, they persist while there are references to them)
; however, they are not distributed to the subkernels.

Comment: You are right! I totally forgot about that.

Comment: Thank you @MarcoB for your edit. I really appreciate that!

Comment: Does the OP's code generate errors for you?  I finally tried it, and it works fine as is.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Huh, indeed, it does not! I could have promised that I had tried it yesterday...